# Terraform multiple values for single variable issue

Tags: azure, variables, terraform

I'm trying to create an Azure application in AD using Terraform.

```
resource "azuread_application" "my_ad_app" {
  display_name = "my_app"

  #API Permissions
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "0000000-000000000000" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
      id   = "df021288-bdef-9214" # User.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "18a4783c662c884" # User.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "9a5d68c3a30" # Application.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    }
```

I will be creating some more Azure AD applications with the same API permissions assigned. There are many API permissions that will be assigned and they are the same for all Azure AD applications that I will be creating. Since the API permissions are same for all the Azure AD applications which I will be creating for, I want to assign the entire `required_resource_access` as a variable.

Something like this.

```
#API Permissions
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
     assign the entire part as a variable here? Example: var.ms_graph_api_permission
     }
```

I tried to add the below as a variable but it doesn't seem to work.

```
variable "ms_graph_api_permission" {
  type = list(string)
  default =

resource_access {
id   = "df021288f22de89214" 
type = "Role"
}

resource_access {
id   = "18a4783e5662c884" 
type = "Role"
}

resource_access {
id   = "9a5d68ac3a30" 
type = "Role"
}
}"
```

This doesn't seems to work. Any idea how to automate this?

I tried using locals.

```
locals {
  resource_access = [
    {
      id   = "df021288-bdde89214" # User.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    },
    {
      id   = "18a4783c-85e5662c884" # User.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    }
  ]
}

resource "azuread_application" "my_ad_app" {
  display_name = "my_app"

  #API Permissions
  required_resource_access {
    for_each   = {
    for index, az_app_id in local.resource_access:
    az_app_id.id => az_app_id
    }

    resource_app_id = "000000000000" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access = How should I pass values here using locals??
```

Comment: Well, it's not a list of strings definitely. It could be a map of strings, but you would have to use a different key (i.e., `resource_access` would have to be different).

Comment: How can I perform this using maps?

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#maps-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing to note to start here is that nested blocks like `resource_access` are not plain data that you can just pass in a variable: they are static configuration constructs declared by the provider in its schema. Therefore you can't "just" pass a whole set of blocks through a variable, but you *can* pass some data that would be used to populate those blocks, and ask the Terraform language to dynamically generate `resource_access` blocks for you based on that data. The rest of this answer is an example of how you can do that.

First, the variable declaration:

```
variable "ms_graph_api_permission" {
  type = list(object({
    id   = string
    type = string
  }))
}
```

This declares that `var.ms_graph_api_permission` is a list of objects where each object must have two attributes -- `id` and `type` -- that are both strings. This seems to match the shape of the data you want to provide through the `resource_access` blocks.

A value of that type would look like what you tried with a local value:

```
[
  {
    id   = "df021288-bdde89214" # User.Read.All
    type = "Role"
  },
  {
    id   = "18a4783c-85e5662c884" # User.Read.All
    type = "Role"
  },
]
```

You can use an expression like the above both as the default value for the variable and in the `module` block that calls the module, when choosing a value for this variable.

Inside the resource block itself you'll need to ask Terraform to generate one `resource_access` block for each element of that list, using a [`dynamic` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "azuread_application" "my_ad_app" {
  display_name = "my_app"

  #API Permissions
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "0000000-000000000000" # Microsoft Graph

    dynamic "resource_access" {
      for_each = var.ms_graph_api_permission
      content {
        id   = resource_access.value.id
        type = resource_access.value.type
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A `dynamic "resource_access"` block specifies a rule for generating zero or more `resource_access` blocks based on some other collection, which in this case is `var.ms_graph_api_permission`. The `content` block describes how to generate the body of each of the blocks, where `resource_access` is a local symbol referring to the current element of `var.ms_graph_api_permission`.

Terraform Core will dynamically expand this to a series of individual `resource_access` blocks before passing the configuration to the provider, so from the provider's perspective this is equivalent to you having written out a series of static `resource_access` blocks as in your original example.